# XCode code signing menu has gone wonky -- how to fix?

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

I have one project where the code-signing popup is all whacked-out.

On a "normal" (*i.e.*, every-other) project, the popup looks something like "Good menu" in this picture, but on one project, it looks like the "Not-good menu":

[image: Code-sign menus, good and not-good]

The "Not-good menu" is from the project about which I'm asking.

I tried quitting & relaunching XCode, but there's no change.

Any ideas what went wrong?  Is there some sort of "un-whack my project" tool?

**EDIT:**

I suspect that the problem is related to the whack-project being not-worked-on for a long time and, hence, missed a "This project created by an older version of XCode" migration.  Is there some sort of "update my project files" tool?

**EDIT:**

On a tip from another forum, I did this:

- close project in XCode.
- Open project.pbxproj (in your filename.xcodeproj package) in a text
  editor. (make a backup first!)
- Remove all lines starting with "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" =
  "blahblah blah Developer";
- save
- Quit & relaunch XCode.
- Reopen project in Xcode.
- Reset the code signing identity you want

Well, there's good news & bad news.

Good news: It builds, and no code-signing errors.  Yay.

Bad news: The popup still looks like the "not-good menu" in my screenshot.

More Bad News: the not-good menu is incomplete so, for example, I can select the client's ad-hoc, but not their app-store (we're sort of hoping to ship the product!)

Comment: Additional info: dozens of other projects all work just fine.  (Like the "good" one in the screenshot.)  I have lots of adhoc & app-store certs on my machine because I do contract work for others, and build their apps for them.  Only this project has this problem; dozens of others work as expected.

Comment: As I said, sometimes you don't get around creating a **new clean project**

Comment: I ended up making a new, clean project and filing a bug with Apple.  Would love to know the true fix, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate all your help, but none of the proposed solutions worked.  I ended up creating a new project and re-building it.

I also duplicated the existing project, stripped out all the code and, as it had the same problem, attached it to the bug I sent to Apple.  Hopefully, future XCodes will be better about this.

EDIT: Found the problem.  It turns out I had inadvertently set the project's base SDK to simulator x.y, vice iOS x.y.  Once I changed that, the codesign menu went back to as-expected.

D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

In my case (frustrated 40 minutes) it was something stupid and annoying,
xcode would not popup the windows with the provisionig profiles, it was still allowing to 
text write "iPhone Develop:blah blah",
the problem lies in the "Editor" menu, make sure you have show setting names and values set correctly.
hope this helps someone,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i .bak "s/\"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY\[sdk=iphoneos\*\].*/\"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]\" = \"iPhone Developer\";/g" project.pbxproj
```

Then open/clean/build/pray/makesacrifice